# What happens when office web apps goes down

Tags: 2013, office-web-apps

I'm looking into how many servers I need for office web apps. If I only have one. What happens if the server goes down? When the person clicks on a document will it just open in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the [default open behavior](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx) configured at Library or SiteCollection-Level.

If set to "Open in Browser", your Clients will get an Error. They must manually select "Edit" in the Document's context menu.